# Paying fees in custom ERC20 tokens in MATIC blockchain

Tags: erc-20, gas, polygon

I came across a statement that I find quite undoable. How can you pay the fees using your custom token in MATIC? Is this doable or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its doable - but relies on a gas station to execute the contract call for you.

You basically send the contract call data you want to execute to a gas station along with the token you want to pay with.

Assume the gas for the contract transaction is $5 worth of ETH but you have $0 ETH but you do have $5 USDC

The gas station withdraws $5 USDC from your wallet and uses its ETH balance to call the contract with the call data you sent it (ETH or MATIC in your case).

This means that you dont need native tokens to call the contract any tokens can be used.